# Detect if MongoDB is started or not, mail the admin if it's not

Tags: mongodb

I have to write a script which will detect if Mongo DB is started or not. Then, if it has stopped, mail the administrator.
I'm very new to Mongo DB, it will be great help if some one can help me out.

Comment: Try to connect to it, if it doesn't make it, then mail that admin.

Comment: One way is to use the `mongo` shell in a bash script to attempt to connect

Answer (score 2):

This script in **Python** will check if your MongoDB server is running and will send you an alert (you have to configure it):

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

try: 
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
except Exception as err:
    msg = MIMEText("Mongo is down\nError:%s" % err)

    msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
    msg['From'] = 'admin@domain.com'
    msg['To'] = 'sysadminguy@domain.com'

    # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
    # envelope header.
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Then you can simply add a **cron** entry that once per minute execute the script:

```
*/1 * * * *  /python_bin_root/python /your_script_root/script.py
```

Comment: can you explain me how to configure this mail function , will it work with localhost ?

Comment: It works with localhost. You have to set the `msg['xxx']` variables with the subject/from/to fields and also the SMTP server in the line `s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')`. More information in http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html